# cv2.putText() displays question marks instead of text

Tags: python, opencv, encoding

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
cv2.putText(frame, person_name, (row.x-10, row.y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX,1.5,(255, 255, 255))
```

[image]
This used to work

The data type is string and it prints out fine. Why is the putText() function is displaying question marks?

P.S. the row is recieved from a database witn pyodbc, the database collation is general cyrillic something something

Answer (score 1):

Are you using unicode? [A little looking around](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4242) shows that *apparently* openCV  (at least `putText()` - I can't really remember any other examples right now that might accept a string as input the same way this function does) doesn't support unicode. [Attempting unicode characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbqcK.jpg) myself, I get the same results (windows 10, openCV3). Sorry buddy, but you're going to have to stick with ASCII characters for now.

Comment: Thank you vdry much